# Set address in /etc/hosts for local php development in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, host

In the past, It was always enough for me to start local development server on address `localhost`, running on port `8008` - Therefore in browser I could access my development server just by entering `localhost:8008` into browser's address bar.

**My Goal**

I must start my local dev server under the address `mysite`, port `8008`. No exceptions.

**What I Tried**

In order to do this, I added `mysite` into my `/etc/host` file like follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost mysite
```

**Problem**

Upon entering `mysite:8008` into address bar of every browser I tried (`Safari`, `Firefox`) was my dev site is correctly displayed. However I cant get it work on Google Chrome. This is what Google Chrome displays upon entering `mysite:8008` into address bar:

> This site can’t be reached mysite refused to connect.
>
> Search Google for mysite 8000
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

However `localhost:8008` works displays my website correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is totally wierd, but for some mysterious reason it looks like Chrome cares for ordering in the `/etc/hosts` file. Problem has been solved by switching order in `localhost` line of `/etc/hosts` file to following:

```
127.0.0.1   mysite localhost
```